# Get array output of one function in another function php

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I have below controller function of codeigniter,

```
public function add_attachments($openid)
{
            $config = array(
                    'upload_path' => './uploads/attachments/',
                    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|doc|pdf',
                    'max_size' => '1024000000',
                    'multi' => 'all'
                ); 
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);   
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            }
            else
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();  
            }
            $new_array = array_column ($data, 'full_path');         
}
```

I can get output of $new_array,

But i want to use this output in another function which is just below that in same class,

example,

```
public function getback()
{
print_r($new_array);
}
```

in short, once 1 function is executed, some values stored in variable and need to use in another function,

How can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: use this line in $this->getback($new_array);  add_attachments in this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass that value within that function as

```
public function add_attachments($openid) {
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './uploads/attachments/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|doc|pdf',
        'max_size' => '1024000000',
        'multi' => 'all'
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
    }
    $new_array = array_column($data, 'full_path');
    $this->getback($new_array);
}

public function getback($new_array = array()) {
    print_r($new_array);
}
```

**Edited**

Passing data using js

```
public function add_attachments($openid) {
   //your code...
   echo json_encode($new_array);exit;
}
```

Now within your ajax success function

```
 success:function(data){
     var data = $.parseJSON(data)
     //send it to your another function
 }
```

Comment: by adding  $this->getback($new_array); in add_attachment function will also execute this method, which i don't want because getback() method is run with another AJAX request, in short there are two AJAX request in form submit button, one is to upload files with dropzone, and then it will submit form as ajax to get return values

Comment: Try using `echo json_encode($new_array);exit;` and then you'll get that array within your `success` function and you can pass that value from there into another function

Comment: super thanks, i could send it with json and parseJSON in jquery, passed it to another function and that was processed by 2nd function on PHP, now worked, thanks